# Filter by Last update only

Tags: toad

I am asking what is the required modification to the chart below as I just want an last update from the results

I need a small help with selecting a max value of a column of two tables. When I run the sql statement below, I get maximum from both tables, ie 2 rows. How can I get the maximum of both of them

i tried with the below solution but i cant insert this

```
WHERE     a.CWDOCID = b.user_data1
       AND d.cworderid = a.cwdocid
       AND c.order_num = b.user_data2
       AND b.user_data2 IN ('1-165818')
       and transid in (select max (transid) from CMZ_ORDERERROR where cworderid=d.cworderid) 
       ORDER BY d.COMPLETEDTIME DESC
select max(transid)
from (select transid from tbltrans union all
      select transid from tbltrans2
     ) t
```